# LockerService throws error when saving a document cookie

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, cookies

I'm getting an error when trying to save a `document cookie` in Lightning Component.

The error I'm receiving is:

**Cannot set property cookie of [object Object] which has only a getter**

Can we not access document cookies in lightning Component with LockerService?

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot write cookies using the Lightning SecureDocument API.

```
    cookie: SecureObject.createFilteredProperty(o, doc, "cookie", {
        writable: false
    })
```

From: https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker/SecureDocument.js#L116

There is more information regarding the Lightning Locker Service rules and APIs at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_rules.htm

Comment: can we use `localStorage` storage in lightning component?

Comment: I assume not. localStorage is on the `window` object, and the SecureWindow object does not list it as accessible. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_rules_secure_window.htm - but it would be worth trying.

Comment: Thanks @Mark for your help and links. Though, just asking if you know of a way to use some kind of storage locally in lightning component, without using server side options (my app requires to kind of keep a tab of local storage variables like timing a timer so that one can go off the page and come back to it later by minimizing app and opening it again and start back from where he left.

Comment: I suggest you raise a case with Salesforce so that they can consider your case and possibly provide access to the APIs you need.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like all the available browser storage APIs are blocked off by Locker. Can you describe in a bit more detail what the user workflow is like so it's clearer how useful the local storage would be? Perhaps SF would consider whitelisting at least one form of local storage.

Comment: @CharlesT - Yes. Our use case involve a Lightning Component that counts time, like a timer. This timer saves state into local storage on timely basis, but since the storage is local,, we were saving per second timing into storage. The app needs to be time critical, so we can't loose time. This was user could close the app, or minimize the app, or simply go through with other tabs or app usage, we can detect and simply evaluate the time as soon as user comes back to the tab again. App itself can be closed from iphone memory, and it still would work next time it is launched.

Comment: Without local storage, we don't have a feasible solution to implement this, and this will simply render our app useless, since using server side storage solution would be very expensive in speed and api calls as well.

Comment: I just found a Known issue but it is #In Review# status, which I've no idea what it means, but if this is considered, then we should have a localStorage option available in Locker Service which would be great. - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IYE6QAO

Comment: Please can someone confirm if this is going to happen or not? LocalStorage option is a must for my component to work, but I don't see any progress on including that in LockerService github project :( ...

Comment: Doug Chasman has stated support in LockerService for localStorage, sessionStorage, and then cookies are in the works

Edit: Adding link to Twitter convo for reference - https://twitter.com/dougchasman/status/786694453541081092

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and latest status on this, much appreciated.